# Get ID if table has one or more row exist for a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose I have a table as below:

```
ID | Account| Status
---+--------+-------
1  | acct1  | A
1  | acct2  | S
1  | acct3  | C
2  | acct4  | C
2  | acct5  | C
3  | acct6  | A
3  | acct7  | C
4  | acct8  | C
4  | acct9  | C
4  | acct10 | C
```

Condition: return ID if accounts do not have any 'A' and 'S' status.

For this case, I only want ID '2' and '4' to be returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `HAVING` and conditional `SUM`:

```
SELECT ID
FROM tab
GROUP BY ID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Status IN ('A', 'S') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

First select id which record don't have 'A' and 'S'. Then get distinct record:

```
Select distinct(ID) as ID
from table_name where id not in
( 
 select ID from table_name where status in('A', 'S')
)
```